# Dismutation of ethanoic acid

Tags: home-experiment

Ethanoic
 (acetic) acid can undergo fermentation by methanogens to create 
$\ce{CH4}$ and $\ce{CO2}$. Is there any way that I could perform this 
reaction without any microorganisms, specifically with the concentration
 of ethanoic acid found in vinegar, for example with UV light and such?

Also, if this is impossible, what species of bacteria is required?

Comment: A UV light would create ozone which would reaction with acetic acid to completely oxidize it to carbon dioxide and water.

Comment: Melting acetate with solid alkali should produce $\ce{CH4}$. Not sure if it could be made economically feasible, though.

Comment: Bugs are great chemists.  I don't think you'll have any luck beating the methanogens at their game ;)